# Firebase data notification cannot click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Hi I want to send image on notification and use data notification
this is my data and 
notification comes with picture. but the notification is not clicked
How can i send clikable ?

```html
  ""data"" : {""click_action"":"".MainActivity"",
 ""body"" : ""new Symulti update 22!"", 
 ""title"" : ""new"", 
""url"":""https://www.blablaaas.com"",
""img_url"":""https://www.image.com/image1""
""}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are implementing code for android, so to make notification clickable you just need to add the pendingIntent with destination Activity name so that you will get the clickable action. Use the below code for reference.

```
 try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, TabHostScreen.class);
    mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent mainPIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon(builder));
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    //start intent on notification tap (MainActivity)
    builder.setContentIntent(mainPIntent);
    //custom style
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
    builder.setCustomContentView(remoteCollapsedViews);
    //builder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteExpandedViews);
    long[] pattern = {500, 500, 500};
    builder.setVibrate(pattern);
    Random rand = new Random();
    NOTIFICATION_ID = rand.nextInt(1000);
    //notification manager
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Comment: I just ad this  setetContentIntent(mainPIntent); and goodd thanks